# How to make layout of struct linear?

Tags: rust

It seems the layout of a struct is not linear. Looks like fields of struct in memory are not in the same order as they are written into the definition of the structure.
Is there a way to ask the compiler to preserve the order of fields?
What other solution of the problem can you suggest?
Any reading?

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main()
{
  let header = ObjectHeader
  {
    x : 1,
    h : 2,
    a : 3,
    f : 4,
    w : 5,
    body : (),
  };

  let object = header.form();
  let borrowed_header : &ObjectHeader = object.borrow();
  dbg!( borrowed_header );

}

//

#[ derive( Debug, Clone ) ]
pub struct ObjectGeneric< Body >
{
  pub x : i64,
  pub h : u32,
  pub a : u8,
  pub f : u16,
  pub w : u32,
  pub body : Body,
}

pub type ObjectHeader = ObjectGeneric< () >;

impl ObjectHeader
{
  pub fn form( self ) -> Object
  {
    let body = ObjectBody { j : 10 };
    Object
    {
      x : self.x,
      h : self.h,
      a : self.a,
      f : self.f,
      w : self.w,
      body,
    }
  }
}

#[ derive( Debug, Clone ) ]
pub struct ObjectBody
{
  pub j : u32,
}

pub type Object = ObjectGeneric< ObjectBody >;

//

impl Borrow< ObjectHeader > for Object
{
  fn borrow<'a>( &'a self ) -> &'a ObjectHeader
  {
    unsafe
    {
      dbg!( &self );
      let result = std::mem::transmute::< &'a Object, &'a ObjectHeader >( self );
      dbg!( &result );
      result
    }
  }
}

//
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:69] &self = ObjectGeneric {
    x: 1,
    h: 2,
    a: 3,
    f: 4,
    w: 5,
    body: ObjectBody {
        j: 10,
    },
}
[src/main.rs:71] &result = ObjectGeneric {
    x: 1,
    h: 2,
    a: 0,
    f: 10,
    w: 5,
    body: (),
}
[src/main.rs:17] borrowed_header = ObjectGeneric {
    x: 1,
    h: 2,
    a: 0,
    f: 10,
    w: 5,
    body: (),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f93dca37950172b33d473ffa68ed3f03)

Comment: Did you take a look at some documentation? https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html

Comment: Thanks, @Netwave. Yes, but it explains neither that fields are shuffled, nor what principle is behind the shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust the order of fields in compiled program can be different to order in code. I think in practice compiler reorders fields to reduce padding

You can use directive `repr(C)` to save original order of fields

```rs
#[repr(C)]
```

[Try modified example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1f8d3f877ed01142fc6163aa8211cbd)

===

Official documentation declares that for default layout, the order of fields is not specified :

```
With the exception of the guarantees provided below, the default layout of structs 
is not specified.
```

And, you can read [counteropinions for saving layout](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html#counteropinions-and-other-notes) and some explanation about saving of current behavior.

Also, if directive `#[repr(C)]` is not used:

- to test that code incorrectly relies on the layout, use `-Z randomize-layout` flag. [The flag is added by Kixiron](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/87868), it randomizes the layout of structs.

Comment: Maybe you can share details of the principle of shuffling?

Comment: There is no "shuffling", and what the compiler does is an implementation detail, but currently it simply orders the fields largest-first. This reduces the size of the structure (by limiting padding) without changing its semantics, or requiring the developer to mess with the "logical" order of the structure.

Comment: Additionally, outside of things like network protocol size, or any binary-only processing where size is critical, having the *order* of struct members be important usually indicates other marginal practices, like type punning, or copying *between types* with memcpy.  If you're following best practices and trusting the compiler, you shouldn't be doing either, and thus your struct layouts should not be important.  Only when "communicating" outside your program in binary (or language, such as interop with C) does layout become important.